# Pycharm Can't run remote python interpreter error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pycharm

I have an aws ec2 instance to which I want to access and work via pycharm but I cannot correctly configure access to the remote terminal.
The steps I do are these:

1. using github and pycharm I clone the project repository and at the start of the program, since there is no configured python interpreter I start the configuration by clicking on the button "configure python interpreter"

[image]

2. then select ssh interpreter and enter the ip address of the aws instance and username ubuntu

[image]
3) as key I choose a previously saved ppk file

[image]

4)continuing with the settings I select the interpreter like the one identified in the path usr/bin/python and as the project directory I select the directory of my project in home/ubuntu/MyProject

[image]

this is what i see after setting up the remote interpreter

[image]

all connection tests are passed successfully but when I run the code I get this error

```
Error running 'main': Can't run remote python interpreter: Error connecting to remote host
```

[image]

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: please mention the version of pycharm you are using

Comment: Try to uncheck "Execute code using sudo".

Comment: @ChintanGotecha pycharm 2020.1.3

Comment: @igrinis I need to execute my code as sudo otherwise it doesn't work

Comment: I suggest deleting both project interpreter and deployment configurations and creating them anew.

Comment: @igrinis I have done it several times but I always get the same error

Comment: Try reinstalling PyCharm. I have  2020.1.3 and it works fine for me.

Comment: One more thing. I have noticed that you map your project into `/tmp` directory. It has a special set of permissions prohibiting deleting files. Try setting project mapping to a normal directory.

Comment: @igrinis /tmp/pycharm_project_181 is the default path to the project, actually the path i choose is /home/ubuntu/MyProjectFolder

Comment: Look for a more verbose description of the error in [PyCharm logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files).

Comment: Connect to the instance via PuTTY as `ubuntu` using the PPK & run `sudo /usr/bin/python --version`. Does all this work as expected?

Comment: finally I found a solution, by default pycharm set the path for the interpreter usr/bin/python but the correct one is usr/bin/python3, now everything works correctly. thanks to @HarishKM comment that made me think of the python version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally I found a solution, by default pycharm set the path for the interpreter usr/bin/python but the correct one is usr/bin/python3, now everything works correctly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with a different cause:
One of the docker volume bindings in the Run Configuration pointed to a non-existing host dir